# Plotting Radiation Pattern for Hermite-Gaussian beams for different modes

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I want to plot the Radiation Pattern for Hermite-Gaussian beams (HG beam) as given in the Figures Ref [Research Paper Fig 2](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.56.005329), where u and v be the beam modes for the Hermite-Gaussian beams

[image: Hermite-Gaussian beams radiation pattern]

The coding is attached here

```
F1[u_, v_, x_, y_,z_]=(1/w0)*(1/Sqrt[Pi*2^(u + v + 1)*u!*v!])*(w[z])^-1*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)*w^2[z]^-1]*HermiteH[v, Sqrt[2] y *w[z]^-1]* HermiteH[u, Sqrt[2] x*w[z]^-1]*Exp[I[k*z + (k (x^2 + y^2))/2*(R[z])^-1 - (u + v + 1) \[Phi]]] 
w0 = 1*10^-6;
zR = 1/2 k*(w0)^2;
k = (2 \[Pi])/\[Lambda];
\[Lambda] = 0.55*10^-6;
w[z_] = w0 Sqrt[1 + (z/zR)^2];
R[z_] = z + (zR)^2/z;
\[Phi] = ArcTan[z/zR];
```

Here I the values for w0 and k, but the plot is not drawn. Moreover, when I draw the intensity distribution for the Hermite-Gaussian beam then its plots becomes clear as

```
F1[m_, n_, x_, y_] =Sqrt[1/(2^(m + n - 1)*Pi*m!*n!)]*HermiteH[m, Sqrt[2] x]*HermiteH[n, Sqrt[2] y]*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
t11 = DensityPlot[(F1[0, 2, x, y]^2), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Hermite Gaussian beam Intensity Distribution]

Guide me where the mistake exist, How to plot the HG beam radiation pattern?

Comment: "Here i assume the values for w0 and k" - you can't just assume, you need explicit values. If you want a plot, your function should evaluate to a number. Also, you should give a reference for the first figure you included.

Comment: What should: `w^2[z]^-1`mean ? Please correct. And what are `u` and `v`? BTW the article is pay for read.

Comment: "the article is pay for read." - the point is that people who do have access can use e.g. their library connections to read it and get more context.

Comment: u and v be the Hermite gaussian (HG) beam modes just as below in figure m and n instead of u, v so changing m and n clearly change the intensity of HG beam. I attached research paper for more clearance plz see the attached.

Comment: Can i guide on this as i attached above my running code  for HG intensity beam?